# MongoDB JsonObject and JsonArray

Tags: mongodb

I'm new MongoDB.
I have a collection is named "surveyCollection".
I insert some data to collection with shell,

```
db.surveyCollection.insert({
   "count":30, 
   "people": [
        {
           "firstName":"John",
           "lastName":"Jason"
        }
   ]
})
db.surveyCollection.insert({
   "count":30, 
   "people": [
        {
           "firstName":"Sarah",
           "lastName":"Smith"
        }
   ]
})
```

And I have data below ( db.surveyCollection.find().pretty());

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5873d0c86c3319a579754d00"),
    "count" : 30,
    "people" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "John",
            "lastName" : "Jason"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5873d0c86c3319a579754d00"),
    "count" : 30,
    "people" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "Sarah",
            "lastName" : "Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know how can I insert a new people to any survey. I mean, I want to have datas like below;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5873d0c86c3319a579754d00"),
    "count" : 30,
    "people" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "John",
            "lastName" : "Jason"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5873d0c86c3319a579754d00"),
    "count" : 30,
    "people" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "Sarah",
            "lastName" : "Smith"
        },
        {
            "firstName" : "George",
            "lastName" : "Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

I mean, how can I reach values in JsonArray?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**$push**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) method to push an item into array of a document as shown below :

```
db.surveyCollection.update(
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5873d0c86c3319a579754d00") },
 { $push: { people: { "firstName" : "George", "lastName" : "Smith"} } }
)
```

This will add the object `{ "firstName" : "George", "lastName" : "Smith"}` to the array `people` in the document of `{"_id" : ObjectId("5873d0c86c3319a579754d00")}`

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been working on for 2 hours.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)